# --Expected token ':'-- in my VS Code, but --Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'return'-- on my browser

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So, after i did some code try to run it as usual from my VSCode extension but i found out that the problem in the chrome inspector was different from problem that my VSCode detected. Here is the code:

```
            const menu = [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'Cappucino',
            price: 35000,
            active: true
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Green tea latte',
            price: 40000,
            active: false
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Fish and chips',
            price: 50000,
            active: false
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            name: 'Tuna sandwich',
            price: 30000,
            active: false
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            name: 'Mineral water',
            price: 8000,
            active: false
        },
        {
            id: 6,
            name: 'French fries',
            price: 18000,
            active: false
        }
        ]

        menu.forEach(item => {
                const li = document.createElement('li')
            li.innerHTML = `${menu.name}<span>Rp ${menu.price}</span>`
            li.setAttribute('data-price', item.price)
            li.addEventListener('click', e => {
                li.classList.toggle('active')
                console.log('Active elements', getActiveCount())
            })
            
            document.getElementById('menu').append(li)
            
            });

        function getTotalPrice() {
            const activeItems = document.querySelectorAll('#menu li.active'),
                return activeItems.length ? Array.from(activeItems).reduce((acc, elem) => acc+=elem.getAttribute('data-price'), 0)
        }
```

Can anyone help me with this?

*Credit: Nabir Abbas*

Comment: A linter would help solve your problem.

Comment: @epascarello like ES Lint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a semicolon instead of a comma here:

```
const activeItems = document.querySelectorAll('#menu li.active');
```

This will fix your "Unexpected token 'return'" error.